# Windows 10 - emulating directory path

Tags: c++, windows-10

I have Windows 10 with the one partition - C. I would like to run the c++ application which has hardcoded paths to some directories on partition D (it fails when I run it from the partition C). Is it possible to deceive somehow that application ? I don't want to create a "physical" partition D.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/subst <- how about a virtual partition?

Comment: Another solution is a virtual disk (vhd or vhdx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the command-line [`SUBST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/subst) command to create a drive letter `D:` that points to any existing folder within the `C:` drive.